# Mapbox - Implement a method once user reached destination in navigation ui

Tags: java, android, firebase, navigation, mapbox

I need to implement a way to send the user to another activity once the user has arrived at the set destination. I tried with the onNavigationFinished() Method but without any success. Can anyone help me?

```
public class RouteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationEngineListener,
    PermissionsListener, MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener, NavigationListener {

  @Override
  public void onNavigationFinished() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RouteActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
} }
```

Comment: Where do you get sent?  IE:  do you get any error messages, etc.?

Comment: How is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: insane how unhelpful the users here are

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ArrivalObserver](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/04962c46c7fd6731158745e959e87709152a82e0/libnavigation-core/src/main/java/com/mapbox/navigation/core/arrival/ArrivalObserver.kt#L24).

The onFinalDestinationArrival is a callback that will be called when you're approaching the destination.